# Session data get lost - Chrome only

Tags: php, google-chrome, session-variables, chromium

Somehow, when calling another script (all other scripts than index.php), all my CMS authorisation data gets deleted. The login boolean and username consists. This only appears using Chrome/Chromium.
The chrome developer tools don't show any errors, only `200 OK` and `304 Not modified`.
This is really annoying since I've changed to Chromium for Firefox being to ressource-heavy.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be really hard to debug without any code or anything.  When you say session data I assume you are referring to your php session.  This has nothing to do with the browser. Are you making sure you aren't changing the domain/subdomain while browsing at all (which will cause you to lose your session).  You can check your php.ini session settings but that shouldn't matter if it is working on other browser.

I'm guessing this is occuring because your session isn't getting started properly OR the session data is getting cleared somehow in your code.

Comment: In every script, there is a `session_start()`. And I'm only accessing $_SESSION by reading values, not by writing. And the session is in fact stored as a cookie. (`PHPSESSID`) And like I said, the behaviour ONLY appears in Chrom-e/ium

Answer (score 0):

Now it appears in Fx too. The problem: The hoster updated to PHP5 and there `register_globals` was set to `On` again.